# Is it dangerous/harmful to increase the voltage supplied to a 12v electromagnet?

Tags: voltage, electromagnet

I have a [12V-rated electromagnet which I bought online](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Electromagnetic-Magnetic-Electronic-Controller-failsafe/dp/B07Y1Z14G5/ref=sr_1_7?dchild=1&keywords=12v%20elektromagnet&qid=1609707906&sr=8-7). As it isn't strong enough for my needs, I tried applying a higher voltage (~20V) which did make it stronger.
It does get a bit warmer after a while but I wanted to know if apart from the additional heat, such an increase in voltage could harm the magnet, as I know that when building my own electromagnet, I can increase the voltage as far as I want as long as the heat doesn't become a problem.

Comment: Such a question is not answerable without technical details of the magnet.

Comment: I would not expect anything that is advertised as rated for 12 volts to last very long with 20 volts applied. Additional heat will likely cause it to fail eventually. Whether that will burn someone or start a fire is impossible to predict.

Comment: In addition to the problem of heating, you may saturate the core. In that case, the efficiency will decline dramatically. That is, much more current will be drawn for little gain in magnetic strength.

Comment: Increase voltage 50% will cause 2.25 times power consumption.

Comment: I agree with Charles, but it could be phrased differently. Apart from the heat, there is not likely to be any real problem. But in order to know whether the heat is excessive, you need to know the temperature  rating of the magnet wire and the actual temperature of the wire. Most likely you don't know those things. So feel free to keep using 20V, but make sure you are prepared for failure of the electromagnet. Only use it when it is being actively supervised by you. And make sure you use it in such a way that there will be no harm if it starts a fire.

Comment: It might affect which freewheel diode you are using, particularly if you use TVS for freewheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Is it strong enough already?

If it's being used without the armature to pick up nails, then it's as strong as you find. If it's being used for its intended purpose of holding a door closed, then it could potentially be made significantly stronger without increasing the drive voltage.

The magnetic field the lock generates depends on the current, and the magnetic circuit through the return plate. If the plate surface is rough, or not flat, or being held at an angle by the door attachment, then small airgaps will reduce the magnetic field and the holding force. You do not need much of an airgap to wreck the holding power, 0.1mm (thickness of a sheet of printer paper) could reduce it to 50% or worse.

If the pole faces of the magnet and return plate show machining marks or are bowed, then carefully [lapp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapping) the two facing surfaces until they are smooth meet properly.

If the return plate is screwed tightly to the door, slacken the attachment screw slightly so that it can float, and rotate slightly, to mate fully with the magnet. You'll notice the return plate has only a single hole in the centre, for this very reason.

It may be that attention to these mechanical details will improve your holding force sufficiently.

### Can you make it stronger with increased voltage?

If the magnetic circuit cannot be improved, then increased voltage, which means current, will improve the magnetic field strength, up to the point when the material becomes saturated. There will be no significant improvement above that point. If you are going to increase the voltage, then plot the increase in holding force versus the increase in voltage. There is no point using it at a voltage higher than necessary.

### What can go wrong with increased voltage?

At the low voltages involved, direct breakdown of the insulation is unlikely. Wire insulation needs to be strong enough to withstand handling, which means it's likely to be good for hundreds of volts. However, beware the kickback when you disconnect the magnet. An increased drive current will means higher energy, which means a higher kickback voltage. This should not be a problem when used with a proper kickback suppression diode.

Heat is the main problem. Current is not, of itself, a problem.

Increase the drive voltage to 20 from 12, and you've increased the power and so the temperature rise by a factor of 2.8 times.

High temperature will at best reduce the life of the insulation, and at worst start a fire.

If you use it for a short while, so that its temperature does not exceed it rated temperature, and allow it to cool down again before using it again, then you can safely tolerate it running at a higher power.

How to determine its rated temperature? How to determine how long you can run it? Measure the winding resistance. Run the magnet at its rated voltage for long enough that it reaches thermal equilibrium. Measure the winding resistance again. Copper increases in resistance by about 0.4% per degree C. This gives you the temperature rise. Now do a timed run at the higher voltage, measuring the winding resistance every few minutes. Stop when the measurement shows you it has reached its previous temperature.

Comment: The problem is that the magnet and the metal plate are already fixed, so I can't make the surfaces match better. But you did answer my question, so thank you!

Comment: Also, if I'm connecting the magnet to a power supply with the positive cable going through a relay module, is a kickback protection still necessary?

Comment: @Mine_Stone A kickback diode will protect both the insulation of the wire in the magnet, and the contacts of the relay. It's worth installing one on the relay contacts if it's not there already, it will prolong the life of the contacts by many orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a door lock, it will be on all the time, and likely unsupervised.  If the magnet were being used only for an intermittent function, such as picking up nails, then I'd say that just giving it shorter on-periods might be enough to compensate for the extra heat.  Given its use as a door lock, I'd have to say that I absolutely would not take the chance of using 20 volts when it's specified for 12 volts.